# Django Testserver fixtures not used

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-fixtures

I wanted to start a testserver in Django so that I am able to test my API via Jasmine/FrisbyJs.

For that I found that `python3 manage.py testserver` would create a test-db and load all the testdata provided in the fixtures, which sound exactly what I need. I am NOT running Django-Testcases ATM.

I created a Fixture called testdata.json and stored it within `./fixtures`.
I also set up my `./projname/settings.py` like that:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Fixture Dir
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fixtures'),
)
```

I also made sure `python3 manage.py loaddata testdata` works, which it does:

```
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

However, running `python3 manage.py testserver testdata.json` or `python3 manage.py testserver testdata` leads to this error:

```
CommandError: Error: No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in the command line.
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

python manage.py testserver [Fixture Name]

eg :

```
python manage.py testserver SampleData
```

SampleData.json file will be in app/fixture/